# All shared preference values are not getting stored after kiling app

Tags: android, radio-button, sharedpreferences

I am testing my app against Samsung Galaxy S4 and I am storing 3 values in shared preferences. My problem here is after killing the app only last value that was selected and stored in the shared preferences is getting retrieved and other values are not getting reflected.

I am retrieving the shared preferences values in `onStart` of the activity.

Below is code for shared preferences:

```
SharedPreferences StoreValue_button;
    SharedPreferences.Editor Storevalues_button;

        StoreValue_button=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        Storevalues_button=StoreValue_button.edit();

if(peramount.isChecked()==true){

                        amount=true;
                        Storevalues_button.clear();
                        Storevalues_button.putBoolean("amount", amount);
                        Storevalues_button.commit();
}
```

In the above code there is a `button` and I am storing the button value once it is checked and reflecting same when activity is started again.

code in `onStart`

```
Setpref_Button=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());

if(Setpref_Button.getBoolean("amount", amount))
        {
            peramount.setChecked(true);
        }
```

In the similar way there are other 2 shared preferences which has the similar code.

My issue here is out of 3 shared preferences only last value is retained once app is started after killing it. I am unable to understand the behaviour.

Comment: a) Try to avoid calling edit() if you don't call commit() afterwards. b) Most likely you don't need to call clear() when setting a preference. It might remove stuff you need.

Comment: @beworker thanks for your response... but I am calling commit after storing and also for 3 shared preference I am using 3 saperate variables not storing in single one... problem only appears after killing the app.. if I don't kill the app it works as expected... please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lot of hardwork... made the code to run correctly.... I followed below procedure.

I don't know some how `default shared preferences` doesn't store all values it is storing only one value..`No idea of this behaviour`...

So removed `default shared preferences` and took only `Shared preferences` with `Mode_Private`... one for one storing value... now everything is working fine..

Below is the code:

```
SharedPreferences StoreValue_button;
    SharedPreferences.Editor Storevalues_button;

StoreValue_button= getSharedPreferences("button",MODE_PRIVATE);
        Storevalues_button=StoreValue_button.edit();

amount=true;
Storevalues_button.clear();
Storevalues_button.putBoolean("amount", amount);
Storevalues_button.commit();
```